# Add border layer to offline map using leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have made offline map using leaflet and tiles. These tiles does not contain countries border or state border. I want to add all countries border as well as state border into these tiles. Here is the code for building map.

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([33.705, -84.3900], 4);
            L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© <a>ABC</a>',
            maxZoom: 11,
            minZoom: 4
        }).addTo(map);

        map.attributionControl.setPrefix(''); 
        var london = new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.09);
        map.addLayer(london);
```

Here is the map tiles without any border lines. How to add border layer using leaflet.

[image]

I am expecting output should look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you will need the latitude/longitude pairs of the points that define that "borders layer". It would be best if you have that points in a geoJSON format. Once you have that data you can iterate through those points and connect them and create a layer.

```
var states = [{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Republican"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-97.22,  48.98],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-109.05, 41.00],
        [-102.06, 40.99],
        [-102.03, 36.99],
        [-109.04, 36.99],
        [-109.05, 41.00]
    ]]
}
}];
L.geoJson(states, {
style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.party) {
        case 'Republican': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
    }
}
}).addTo(map);
```

Of course, those points need to be logically grouped, so you can connect the right points. Be sure to check out this link http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html